# Correct architectual way to send "datagrams" via TCP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, packet, datagram

I need to transmit full byte packets in my custom format via TCP. But if I understand correctly TCP is streaming protocol, so when I will call `send` method on sender side, there is not guaranty that it will be received with same size on receiver side when call `recv` (It can be merged together with Nagle's algorithm and then splited when will not fit into frame or when not fit to buffer).

UDP provides full datagrams so there is no such issue.

So question is: what will be the best and correct way to `recv` same pacakges as it was `send`, with same size, with no glue. I develop using python.

I think I can use something like `HDLC` but I am not sure that iterating throug each byte will be best choice. 
Maybe there are some open-source small examples for this situation or it is discribed in books?

Comment: What do you mean by "no glue"? No indicators around the individual telegrams to show their begins and ends? If that's the case, why? Because it's by far the most common way to solve this kind of situation.

Comment: By "no glue" I mean that I need to take individual telegrams, not stream chunks with several telegrams in one stream chunk. Ok, so common way is to add some indicators (several bytes) between my packets on sender side and parse it on receiver? If this bytes will present in packet I need to escape it, it looks like not efficient but I will consider it. I also thought about adding real packet sizes between packets to know how many bytes I need for next full packet and it will help to make decision whether is full packet in current chunk or in next, but maybe there are some standard algorithms?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TCP is only an octet stream this is not possible without glue, either around your data (i.e. framing) or inside your data (structure with clear end).

The way this is typically done is either by having a delimiter (like `\r\n\r\n` between HTTP header and body) or just prefix your message with the size. In the latter case just read the size (fixed number of bytes) and then read this number of bytes for the actual message.